# Text manipulation with vim (or maybe shell)

Tags: bash, vim, join, scripting, awk

I have one file full with records like this:

```
"Full name","URL-style name","key_1a","key_2a"
"Full name","URL-style name","key_1b","key_2b"
"Full name","URL-style name","key_1c","key_2c"
...
```

I have another file full with records like this:

```
"URL-style name","key_1a","key_2a"
"URL-style name","key_1b","key_2b"
"URL-style name","key_1c","key_2c"
...
```

Knowing that (`"key_1","key_2"`) is a primary key (unique), I'd like to add in the second file the `"Full name"` column.

How would you do this? I'm looking for a solution with `vim` or in `bash shell script`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a modified version of your sample data:

#### file1

```
"Full nameA","URL-style name","key_1a","key_2a"
"Full nameB","URL-style name","key_1b","key_2b"
"Full nameC","URL-style name","key_1c","key_2c"
```

#### file2

```
"URL-style name1","key_1a","key_2a"
"URL-style name2","key_1b","key_2b"
"URL-style name3","key_1c","key_2c"
```

#### Processing

As noted in a comment, one limitation of the `join` command is that it can only join on a single column, but the question has a compound key with two columns. There are ways around that, of course: basically, you reformat the inputs to `join` so that the composite column is identifiable as a single column under the delimiter used, and you have to ensure that the data in each file is sorted correctly in order of that composite column. Nevertheless, `join` is probably the way to do it; there's just some prep-work and post-processing required. Also, Bash v4 has 'process substitution' which is very useful for this command.

1. Generate a joinable file from `file1` with the data we need.

   There are several ways to do this; both `sed` (somewhat inscrutably) or `awk` could be used:

   ```
   $ sed 's/\([^,]*\),[^,]*,\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/\2:\3,\1/' file1
   "key_1a":"key_2a","Full nameA"
   "key_1b":"key_2b","Full nameB"
   "key_1c":"key_2c","Full nameC"
   $ awk -F, '{ printf "%s:%s,%s\n", $3, $4, $1 }' file1
   "key_1a":"key_2a","Full nameA"
   "key_1b":"key_2b","Full nameB"
   "key_1c":"key_2c","Full nameC"
   $
   ```
2. Generate a joinable file from `file2` with the data we need:

   ```
   $ sed 's/\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)/\2:\3,\1/' file2
   "key_1a":"key_2a","URL-style name1"
   "key_1b":"key_2b","URL-style name2"
   "key_1c":"key_2c","URL-style name3"
   $ awk -F, '{ printf "%s:%s,%s\n", $2, $3, $1 }' file2
   "key_1a":"key_2a","URL-style name1"
   "key_1b":"key_2b","URL-style name2"
   "key_1c":"key_2c","URL-style name3"
   $
   ```
3. Given this preprocessing, a straight `sort` suffices to get the data ready for `join`.

   ```
   $ join -t, -o 2.2,0,1.2 \
   >      <(awk -F, '{ printf "%s:%s,%s\n", $3, $4, $1 }' file1 | sort) \
   >      <(awk -F, '{ printf "%s:%s,%s\n", $2, $3, $1 }' file2 | sort)
   "URL-style name1","key_1a":"key_2a","Full nameA"
   "URL-style name2","key_1b":"key_2b","Full nameB"
   "URL-style name3","key_1c":"key_2c","Full nameC"
   $
   ```
4. And now we need to post-process the colon into a comma:

   ```
   $ join -t, -o 2.2,0,1.2 \
   >      <(awk -F, '{ printf "%s:%s,%s\n", $3, $4, $1 }' file1 | sort) \
   >      <(awk -F, '{ printf "%s:%s,%s\n", $2, $3, $1 }' file2 | sort) |
   > sed 's/":"/","/'
   "URL-style name1","key_1a","key_2a","Full nameA"
   "URL-style name2","key_1b","key_2b","Full nameB"
   "URL-style name3","key_1c","key_2c","Full nameC"
   $
   ```

Clearly, you can choose any appropriate character instead of a colon; <kbd>Control-A</kbd> (0x01) is unlikely to appear in your HTML.

This assumes that, as shown, your CSV data has no commas in the strings.  If you have commas inside the strings, then life is much harder; you need a proper CSV interpreter to handle the data.  Perl has [`Text::CSV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV) and there's also [`csvfix`](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/).

Comment: Hi! I write your answer as the good one because you've put me on the right track: I had to put first the key, then the data, so there are no "sorting problems" anymore (see my comments to H.-Dirk Schmitt's answer)

Comment: No if I try `:v/:/` under `vim` for the resulting "joined" file, looking for line that aren't joined (= that dont have the `:` char), the result is: `Pattern found in every line: :`. Thank you **`;^)`**

Comment: @OlivierPons There is no need to preprocess the files to force them into a format for `join` when `awk` can handle the whole job very easily.

Answer (score 1):

In `awk`:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$3$4]=$1;next}($2$3 in a){print a[$2$3]","$0}' file1 file2
"Full name","URL-style name","key_1a","key_2a"
"Full name","URL-style name","key_1b","key_2b"
"Full name","URL-style name","key_1c","key_2c"
```

Answer (score 0):

The command you are searching for is `join`.

Please see [`man join`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/join) for detailed information.

If you get an error like `pfull.txt:6: is not sorted` you may either sort the input files before with the `sort` command, or give the `--nocheck-order` option a try.

Comment: I've changed all the records of the #1 file so that they are like `Full name:URL-style#key_1#key_2"` and of the #2 file so that they are like `URL-style#key_1#key_2"`. If I try `join -t: -1 2 -2 1 pfull.txt psmall.txt` then I get an error: `join: pfull.txt:6: is not sorted:`.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the sorting order `sort` of `vim` doesnt sort like `join` expects. Do you know how I could do? How I could sort properly for "`join`"? I tried also `cat pfull.txt | sort > pfull2.txt` but the `sort` bash utility doesn't sort like `join` expects as well.

Comment: One limitation of the `join` command is that it can only join on a single column, but the question has a compound key with two columns.  There are ways around that, of course: basically, you reformat the inputs to `join` so that the composite column is identifiable as a single column under the delimiter used, and you have to ensure that the data in each file is sorted correctly in order of that composite column.  Nevertheless, `join` is probably the way to do it; there's just some prep-work and post-processing required.  `bash` v4 has 'process substitution' which is very useful.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done: I've explained this in my #1 comment (here): I've converted the first "reference" file into a text like `Full name:URL-style#key_1#key_2` with in mind using the **`:`** as the separator, so that the second column will be `URL-style#key_1#key_2`, and in the second file, I modified it as well this way: `URL-style#key_1#key_2` so that using the **`:`** as the separator, there will be only one column.

Comment: But the problem is about how `vim` and the utility `sort` sort the strings: `sort` doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have to match entries with each other, since data is in the same order in both files:

**Use Vim VISUAL BLOCK mode.**

Open both files in Vim in two windows (`:sp <filename>` or `:vsp <filename>` will help with that), start block selection of your desired text with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>, copy with <kbd>y</kbd>.

Move between windows with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>h  j  k  l</kbd>, depending if you have vertical or horizontal splitting.

Position you cursor where you want to paste your clipboard data, press <kbd>p</kbd>.